# Rails 4.1.2 Eager Load Doesn't Kill N+1 Query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, eager-loading

Rails: 4.1.2, Ruby: 2.1.1

I have an `Article` class, which is `commentable` and `has_many :comments`

```
module Commentable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    has_many :comments, :as => :commentable
  end
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true, :touch => true
  belongs_to :user

  #other codes....
end
```

when display the article, I'd like to load all releated information

```
@item = Article.includes(:tags, {:comments => :user}).where(id: params[:id]).first
```

and it does preload tags and comments object.

but when I render `comments`, the comments object and user objects get loaded again.

```
= render @item.comments
```

from log:

[image: development log]

Comment: please specify Rails version.

Comment: thanks, i have the same problem(eager loading polymorphic records). +1

Comment: what if you comment the default_scope in user?

Comment: I'm seeing a "User Load" earlier in the log, could this be something that inverse_of would solve? Maybe your view is using it in a way that AR isn't expecting? EDIT Errr, nvm Rails 4.1.2 should try to inverse automatically I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found out that `Rails` can’t include `polymorphic` associations. Calling `preload` still loads the related models in as few SQL statements as possible, but does not allow for querying on the related models.